# Including libraries from vcpkg only

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, cmakelists-options

I want to install and use libraries only from vcpkg.
Currently, i placed my vcpkg installation in my project, so i think i can just carry the project wherever i want and it will work automatically as `npm install` but without running a command.

I code in vscode on Ubuntu. I am using assimp, imgui, opengl, glfw3 and glad libraries.

i don't know how i can include those libraries from vcpkg. I am so confused about the methods i saw when researching.

Some people use `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)`, or `find_library(OPENGL_LIBRARY OpenGL or GL )`.
Sometimes they use add_library().

Sometimes they use `target_include_directories()` alongside these above or just `include_directories()`.

I don't understand what the pipeline is for this instructions.
The only thing i understood is that i will always use `target_link_libraries()` to my target after pull all these libraries somehow.

Everyone copy and pastes same tutorial information everywhere without giving any specific detail.

For example for installing OpenGL everyone says find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED). But this tries to find the module lopenGL as if it is in the system directory.

I am not even talking the ones throws things like set cmake_toolchain etc.

I really need an explanation for these issues.

I tried all these above to make it work but i end up like i am throwing something to the wall and see what sticks. Which is not a method i like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is first set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` see the [documentation here](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration.html).

If you are using `VSCode` (with CMakeTools for VSCode) then you can change the `settings.json` by adding this:

```
{
  "cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "path/to/vcpkg_root_folder/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
  }
}
```

Or you can pass it to cmake directly via a (define) `-D` flag:

```
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/same/path/as/above
```

By specifing the toolchain file you can then freely use `find_package(PACKAGE)` to get **predefined** variables for linking, include folders, etc... The toolchainfile somewhat guarantees that the first libraries CMake will find and use are the ones downloaded/installed by vcpkg.

An example of such predefined variables for `find_package(OpenGL)` can be [found here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html)

EDIT: If you are confused by the `find_package` then to briefly explain:

Think of it as just a function that loads a specific `.cmake` file. This file contains (or creates) said **predefined variables** and check that these files exist - the behaviour of the file that it loads usually depends on what kind of a file it loads (either `*config.cmake` or `find*.cmake`). As the naming suggests, `find*.cmake` most of the time contains logic on where to look for the needed files, while `*config.cmake` already knows of the existence of said files and just configures the variables. Without these variables you would have to manually look for the files and define the paths yourself. e.g.

```
g++ some_file.cpp -Lpath/to/library/folder -lname_of_library ...
```

If one framework contains multiple libraries (like openCV) you would have to type out all the libraries by hand. But with a predefined variable you could just:

`target_link_libraries(target ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES})`
and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you tell me what is the difference between find_package and find_library ?

Comment: @deepfreeze `find_library` is something that you should (at this point) not worry about. It's a helper function to which you can specify paths and hints on where to look for a specific library. IF found - it then stores the result into a specified variable. This is a function that you will (among others) most likely find in the `find*.cmake` files. For development purposes (with the use of `vcpkg`) you are only interested in the `find_package()`. In short, `find_library` is usually part of `.cmake` files that `find_package()` may or may not use.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much, CMake's documentation can be very confusing, especially to someone new. I've been there myself. Good luck with your endeavours.

Comment: Oh and i have a small question. I added assimp library to my lib (lib/assimp) folder. and used it in my cpp as <assimp/Importer.h> and it worked. But i didn't even added it to cmake or anything. If it worked why do we need cmake to link things ?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with the `assimp` library, but chances are it's a header-only library in which case you do not need to link the library itself. Another possibility is that a different target is already linking against it. However judging by your include directive being `<assimp/Importer.h>` and not `"assimp/Importer.h"` you are most likely accessing an installed header (in standard include paths) and not the actual local header file. Unless your cmake is configured to include that directory. But again, without seeing the whole project I can provide only a wild guess.